# How to generate dynamic lambda expression from Entity

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-6

In following function I am passing list of an TEntity. I want to pass all the columns in TEntity to `x.ColumnsToUpdate(c => c));` as lambda expression. How to achieve it? Please help.

```
public virtual void BulkUpdate(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    if (entities == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entities));

    EFBatchOperation.For(_Context, _Entities)
        .UpdateAll(entities,x => x.ColumnsToUpdate(c => c));
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting? What is the problem? What you want to accomplish?

Comment: I am not facing any issue. x.ColumnsToUpdate(c => c)) method accepts lambda expression. I want to pass all the columns present in entities.

Comment: You are using an optimized version of Entity Framework  updates. This optimization doesn't seem to support the concept of "all columns", if it is the one here: https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities/blob/a5abc50b7367d64ca541b6e7e2e6018a500b6d8d/EntityFramework.Utilities/EntityFramework.Utilities/EFBatchOperation.cs  So, I think you're out of options: either you specify all columns or fall back to standard EF updates.

Comment: @A.Chiesa Yes I am using the same. That's why I was looking option to dynamically generate column names and pass it. Do you have any idea, how to achieve the bulk update then? Or any other nuget package which will achieve it.